# Why is my pickadate calendar backwards?

Tags: javascript, pickadate

I've looked through all the documentation, can't find any reason why [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/) would be this way:

[image]

I'm not giving it any arguments:

js : `$('.datepicker').pickadate({});`

html : `<input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker">`

Comment: how do you initialize it ? html/js

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli when I initialize it with no arguments it still does the same thing:   js : `$('.datepicker').pickadate({});` html : `<input id="date" type="text" class="form-control datepicker">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to make sure you're not including the rtl.css stylesheet, this can cause things to look reversed.

Comment: For reference, see [rtl languages](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#translations_rtl).